# Hibernate @MapKey in the self table

Tags: hibernate, collections, dictionary, mapping

I have a requirement where the entity object needs to have a Map collection with the MapKey is as column in the same table. The entity object Fund can have related Funds with each fund having a unique fund type. I need to have the related funds as a Map where FundType is an enum class. Hibernate is not persisting the relatedFunds into the table. Only the parent fund is getting inserted.  Here is my entity object for the same:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="T_FUND")
public class Fund {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name="FUND_TYPE", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
    protected FundType fundType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mainFund", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @MapKey(name="fundType")    
    protected Map<FundType,Fund> relatedFunds;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = FundImpl.class,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    protected Fund mainFund;

    @Column(name="FULL_NAME", nullable = false, length = 255)
    protected String fullName;

 }
```